# Managing CUDA with Conda environments

Tags: tensorflow, virtualenv, conda

I work with Tensorflow and PyTorch and manage each project that I work on inside of a Conda environment. This allows me to share projects and update my stack without breaking old projects. I am trying to get Conda to manage Cuda within an environment as well. Is this possible? I want old projects to be maintained whenever I update to newer versions of Cuda and CUDnn. Is there a way for Anaconda do this?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have you tried installing one of the binstar packages (anaconda search -t conda cuda)?

Comment: The Cuda toolkit does appear. So maybe it does manage this, but it seems there could still be a problem if the NVIDIA drivers are updated. I guess I'm trying to see if Conda environments are enough for reproducibility or if I should look at Docker.

Comment: It is better to have two separate conda environment for Tensorflow and PyTorch. Latest version of Tensorflow support different `CUDA` and `cuDNN` versions than the older version of Tensorflow. Two different software packages will have different dependencies.Check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) tested configuration for Tensorflow.Thanks!